# HitBuilder method setAll() not working in Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

I have created a `Hitbuilder` instance and passed  `HashMap<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>` params info. into the `HitBuilder` but could not find any info. of the Keys and values of HashMap on Dashboard.

Although I can see screenName, category, eventName and label.

Below is the snippet I'm doing.

```
     Tracker t = getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
                t.setScreenName(screenName);
                t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                            .setCategory(category)
                            .setAction(action)
                            .setLabel(label)
                            .setValue(value)
                        .setAll(params) // cannot find params information
                        .build());
```

Also passing like below also don't show me the values:

```
     Tracker t = getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
                t.setScreenName(screenName);
                t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                            .setCategory(category)
                            .setAction(action)
                            .setLabel(label)
                            .setValue(value)
                            .set("param1", "test1")
                            .set("param2", "test2")
                        .setAll(params) 
                        .build());
```

Any answer or comment is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What keys are you passing? For those curious here is the [reference docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/analytics/HitBuilders.HitBuilder.html#setAll(java.util.Map%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E)) for the method. Only valid [Measurement Protocol parameters](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters) will show up in the results. And the parameter must start with an `&`. For example if for some reason I wanted to set the geoId of a particular event I could do that as follows:

```
 Tracker t = getTracker(TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
            t.setScreenName(screenName);
            t.send(new HitBuilders.EventBuilder()
                        .setCategory(category)
                        .setAction(action)
                        .setLabel(label)
                        .setValue(value)
                        .set("&geoid", "21137")
                        .build());
```

Before sending random combinations of hit parameters I would encourage you to verify that the hits are valid using the [Hit Builder Tool](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/hit-builder/).